# Javascript XOR operation (trying to understand!)

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, xor

I've been researching the caret (XOR) operator in Javascript, but i'm having a heck of a hard time understanding.

Can someone explain why, for example, 1 ^ 1 = 0?

I have some code someone wrote, and they are doing the following:

```
if (shouldBeCollapsed ^ 1)
{
   //code to collapse section of page.
}
```

But if the shouldBeCollapsed variable is equal to 1, the condition fails. I'm just trying to understand the logic behind the ^ operator, and it's kind of confusing me!

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever wrote this code should be severely punished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the definition of XOR. X ^ Y is 1 iff X != Y.
Thus, if X and Y are both 1, then XOR is 0.

The truth table is as follows:

```
X  Y  X^Y
0  0   0
0  1   1
1  0   1
1  1   0
```

`X ^ Y` is logically equivalent to `(X && !Y) || (!X && Y)`

Comment: yes and `shouldBeCollapsed ^ 1`  evaluates to `true` when `shouldBeCollapsed != 1`

Comment: Also simply understood as, "True when either are true, but not when both are true."

Comment: @NedNowotny Nice way to say it.

Comment: @Trenin: I fixed your truth table for you :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes - saw that.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
2 ^ 1 = 3
In binary
10 ^ 01 = 11
```

At a bitwise level, `A^B = 1 if A != B`

`shouldBeCollapsed` looks like a boolean variable in which case you are doing it wrong. What you are looking for is :

```
if (shouldBeCollapsed) { 
    // Code to collapse
}
```